# Multiple views on android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to build an activity in my current application which would split the activity into 2 halves with one running a video and the other running high intense graphics. Is this possible? I have been looking around online and havent been able to come across anything.

The closest I came with my research is that on Note 2 you can have a browser and youtube on the same screen. In this scenario its two different applications being shown on the same screen. Jelly bean may have this feature or it could be a feature of Note 2 itself.

I'm afraid I do not have any code developed at this point to show here as I'm still researching if this is even possible. Any guidance/direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?

Comment: I havent come across this. This should be a good first step. Thanks ! much appreciated.